# The author said obvious. If $I = \cup_{i=1}^{n} I_i$, then $|I| = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |I_i|$.

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I am reading "Calculus II" by Shizuo Miyajima.

Let $I := [a_1, b_1] \times [a_2, b_2] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$.
Let $|I| := \prod_{i=1}^{n} (b_i - a_i)$.
Let $I_i = [c_{i1}, d_{i1}] \times [c_{i2}, d_{i2}] \times \cdots \times [c_{in}, d_{in}]$ for $i \in \{1, \cdots, m\}$.
Let $|I_i| :=  \prod_{k=1}^{n} |d_{ik}-c_{ik}|$ for $i \in \{1, \cdots, m\}$.
Let $I_k^\circ \cap I_l^\circ = \emptyset$ for $k \ne l$. ($I^\circ$ is an interior of $I$.)

The author wrote that the following fact was obvious, but I cannot prove that:

> If $I = \cup_{i=1}^{m} I_i$, then $|I| = \sum_{i=1}^{m} |I_i|$.

Please tell me the proof.

Comment: What axioms are you working from? "Please tell me the proof" is not very helpful here because it's not clear what is given - and, from what you've written, it looks like the author is asserting an *axiom* rather than a *theorem*, saying that the measure of a union of disjoint sets is the sum of the measures of the sets. (But, on the other hand, if this book has defined $|I|$ to be Jordan or Lebesgue measure, there is indeed a proof of this fact)

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thank you for your comment. I think this fact is a simple proposition and we don't need to know what a measure is. This book is an elementary book and the author didn't write what a measure is.

Comment: Presumably $|\cdot|$ is Lebesgue measure, in which case the measure of the union of disjoint intervals is indeed the sum of the measure of the intervals. But it seems strange to introduce Lebesgue measure in a book titled *Calculus II*.